# Poisson process of customer arrivals

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Suppose that average 30 customers arrive per hour at a shop in accordance with a Poisson process. Find the probability that

1. At most two customers arrive during a 6 minute period
2. the shopkeeper will wait between 3 to 5 minutes for the arrival of the first customer.

I could solve the first part, it was direct application of the formula. I am unable to understand what does the second part mean? Also, how do I approach such problems. Like I am unable to link time between Poisson processes and number of Poisson processes? Thank you.

Comment: Let $(N_t)$ denote the Poisson process. In 2. you will be looking at the probability $\mathbb{P}(N_3=0,N_5-N_3\geq1)$. Calculate this using the Markov property.

Comment: Time of the first arrival is exponential RV $T\sim Exp(30)$.